# PostgreSQL ERROR: cannot freeze committed xmax

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, autovacuum

First of all, I am new to PostgreSQL database.

In my PostgreSQL log I can see errors bellow and I don't know what is wrong or what I should change.

```
2018-03-29 10:54:38 CEST::@:[5059]: CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "jiradb.public.propertyentry"
2018-03-29 10:55:38 CEST::@:[5144]: ERROR:  cannot freeze committed xmax 710196
2018-03-29 10:55:38 CEST::@:[5144]: CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "jiradb.public.propertyentry"
2018-03-29 10:56:38 CEST::@:[5182]: ERROR:  cannot freeze committed xmax 710196
2018-03-29 10:56:38 CEST::@:[5182]: CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "jiradb.public.propertyentry"
2018-03-29 10:57:38 CEST::@:[5208]: ERROR:  cannot freeze committed xmax 710196
2018-03-29 10:57:38 CEST::@:[5208]: CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "jiradb.public.propertyentry"
```

I use default vacuum settings except this one parameter:

```
vacuum_cost_limit = 200
```

We are using PostgreSQL `9.4.16`, single node solution on RedHat 7.

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you upgrade recently? Is `propertyentry` a materialized view?

Comment: Yes, I upgraded our DB from 9.2 to 9.4.16 via `pg_upgrade`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two leads:

If "jiradb.public.propertyentry" is a **materialized view**, you might be running into a bug that was fixed with the release of 9.4.17 on 2018-03-01. [The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-4-17.html)

> - Repair pg_upgrade's failure to preserve `relfrozenxid` for materialized views (Tom Lane, Andres Freund)
>
>   This oversight could lead to data corruption in materialized views
>     after an upgrade, manifesting as “could not access status of
>     transaction” or “found xmin from before relfrozenxid” errors. The
>     problem would be more likely to occur in seldom-refreshed materialized
>     views, or ones that were maintained only with `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY`.
>
>   If such corruption is observed, it can be repaired by refreshing the
>     materialized view (without `CONCURRENTLY`).

The last line also hints how to repair this.

Or, if you **upgraded from Postgres 9.2 or older**, this other issue resulting in `cannot freeze committed xmax <xid>` may be yours:

- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1erVTy-0005Lp-8p%40gemulon.postgresql.org
- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAPYLKR6yxV4=pfW0Gwij7aPNiiPx+3ib4USVYnbuQdUtmkMaEA@mail.gmail.com

Fixed, but not released, yet. Should be in 9.4.18.

Comment: Can be this reason why I have hit ratio 74.80 on that DB?